# Programmatically update prices from CSV

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, script

Can someone suggest me a script or the correct way to update products prices trought a csv file? I use Magento 1.9.1 and i have simples and configurables products

I have found the prices is stored in **catalog_product_entity_decimal**

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Magmi (https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git).

"Stolen" from magmis WIKI:

> Magmi is a Magento Mass Importer developed as a magento DATABASE client, (ie not a magento extension) , that operates directly in SQL and is the result of a deep analysis of the Magento Database Model. The first magmi goal was catalog import & update.
>
> it can create products or update an existing catalog and deal with HUGE data (Millions of products could be managed by magmi,but even above a few 1000’s , you’ll see the real difference with dataSlow)

Main Features

- It provides decent speed compared to Dataflow (depending on server config & number of attributes, 70-100 rows/sec is standard magmi speed).
- It supports Dataflow export CSVs file & also some enhanced CSV syntax for dealing with custom options import & media gallery import.
- it works for multistore
- It supports remote image urls for image related attributes (in this case, speed is affected by image download)
- It also provides Generic SQL Datasource Plugin that enable getting data to be imported into magento from another legacy database instead of CSV.
- Can handle configurables (through configurables plugin)
- Can handle related, upsell & cross-sell (using Relater & upsell/cross-sell plugin)

UI

> Magmi provides a Web UI for configuration & running, however,it can be called via cli for automation.

Comment: I have just take a look at your link, maybe with Magmi i need root access? i don't have root access

Comment: There is no need for root acces. You can use the UI.

Comment: Please upvote/accept if it works für you. Thanks :)

Comment: Where i can find all the correct procedure to install Magmi to start working with it?

Comment: Please take at look at the WIKI: http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Installing_Magmi

Comment: I tried to install and configure Magmi, i tried to import a csv file to update prices and i have problem, configurable product price is not updated, just simple product child are updated but magento 1.9.1 take the price from parent. maybe i wrong something?

Comment: You have to enable configarble item proccessoir in UI and adjust your CSV ... more information here: http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Configurable_Item_processor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58898/discussion-between-ivan-and-sv3n).

Comment: I have enable "Configurable Item processor v1.3.7a" and build a csv with "sku,price" but just simple prices are updated and not the configurable

Comment: Back in 5-6h. You can also ask on magmis github page.